# How can I update the emulator to node v14 in firebase-tools-instant-win.exe?

Tags: npm, firebase-tools

In Firebase cloud functions, I want to use JavaScript optional chaining and it seems only available in node.js version 14. In package.json in the functions directory, engines is set to node 14. But how can I update node.js from version 12 to version 14 in firebase-tools-instant-win.exe on my local machine?